# I want to append the name of the file on the top of that file using bash script

Tags: linux, sed, bash-scripting

I want to add `void mainfunction()` on the top of a file. I am reading the actual name of the file from another file and the name of the main function from another file. I was using:

```
sed -i 1i void $name_main() $name_c
```

where the name of the file is stored in `name_c` and the `name_main` stores the name of the main function. But this command is appending `void $main_name()` on the top of the file. How can I do this?

Comment: This question would be better suited for [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: maybe stackoverflow actually, bash scripting is it's own "language", sort of

Answer (score 1):

You need to use double-quotes, like this:

```
sed -i "1i void $name_main()" "$name_c"
```

#### Explanation

Consider single-quotes:

```
sed -i '1i void $name_main()' '$name_c'
```

The shell does not interfere with single-quoted strings.  They are passed on to `sed` unchanged.  Hence, the literal string `$name_main` will appear in the output.  Likewise, this command will try to act on the filename `$name_c` rather than the name given by the value of that shell variable.

Consider no quotes:

```
sed -i 1i void $name_main() $name_c
```

With no quotes, the shell will perform word-splitting.  This can cause all manor of problems.  Also, without quotes, the shell expects that parentheses will start a subshell.  You don't want that either.

With double-quotes, shell variable substitution will occur but word splitting will not.  It is the right choice here.